# Python: Compare the key against the values of each key pair values in a dictionary based on the type set in a separate dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given two separate example dictionaries:

```
fruit_type = {'apple': 'stonefruit', 'peach': 'stonefruit', 'pear': 'stonefruit','orange': 'citrus', 'lemon': 'citrus', 'tangerine': 'citrus'}
similar_fruit = {'apple': ['peach', 'pear'], 'peach': ['apple', 'pear'], 'pear': ['apple', 'peach'], 'orange': ['lemon', 'tangerine'], 'lemon': ['orange', 'tangerine'], 'tangerine': ['orange', 'lemon']}
```

What is the most efficient method of comparing each of the keys against the values in the `similar_fruit` dictionary based on their values in the other dictionary `fruit_type`?

I have what seems like a naive working implementation below:

```
same_type = False

for fruit in similiar_fruit:
  for comparison in similiar_fruit[fruit]:
    if fruit_type[fruit] == fruit_type[comparison]:
      same_type = True
```

It might be helpful to note that there are only 2 types of fruits at all times (stonefruit, citrus), and the keys in the first dictionary line up with the keys in the second dictionary in terms of same keys (apple, peach, pear, orange, lemon, tangerine), not necessarily the order of the keys.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example is nice and concise.  But what are you looking for as a result?  Obviously, after running the code above, you'll end up with just "same_type == True", which isn't very interesting.  Is there some specific data structure you're looking to have result?  Or are you just looking for the case where the inner if clause fails? That would seem to be the true interesting result, as from your example data, you expect all the tests to succeed, right?  If that's the case, having a failure case in your data would be better (I didn't just miss it, did I?)

Comment: So the goal is the return the boolean value to check whether the `similar_fruit` keys match up to the values based on their `fruit_type` to make sure that the bundle of fruits, for example, would be something that can be stored together.
So yes, I'm checking to see if the inner clause fails, where that combinations would not be a viable bundle.

With that said, yes for this instance a failure case in the data would be preferred.

Comment: ha!  Thought so.  So if you put the above code in a function, and returned False if the comparison failed, and return True at the bottom, you'd have a function that gave you your desired result, right?  So then it's a question of a more efficient algorithm, yes?

Comment: Yup that is exactly right

Comment: It also might be helpful to note that there are only 2 types of fruits at all times, and the keys in the first dictionary line up with the keys in the second dictionary in terms of same keys, not necessarily the order of the keys.

Comment: I can't think of a better choice off hand, but there may very well be one.  My question to you, as a manager of programmers and a teacher of programming, is "who cares if there's a better way?".  I think your code does what you want.  Is this an academic exercise, your are you just getting real work done?  If the latter, I'd suggest calling this good enough and moving on.  This isn't to say that I'm not also curious if someone else can provide a good answer to the riddle of the perfect implementation.  One reason to care would be if you anticipate a MUCH larger dataset.

Comment: This segment of the program is a part of a larger program that needs the runtime complexity to stay with a certain limit due to constraints that are predetermined. So I guess to answer the question, we might need to look at different implementations to the entire program if this segment complexity cannot be improved.

Comment: Good enough.  Then let's hope someone smarter than me comes along ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188531/discussion-between-steve-and-tcc).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any other way to simplify that!  However, I would make the change of starting `same_type = True`, and make the comparison as:

```
if fruit_type[fruit] != fruit_type[comparison]:
  same_type = False
  break
```

That way as soon as a comparison is incorrect, it will fail the inner clause to prevent comparison overwriting, and stop the loop.

Also, if you were looking to simply create a dictionary of each fruit and make a list of which ones they are similar to rather than starting with two dictionaries to compare, I wrote a code to accomplish that here:

```
fruit_type = {'apple': 'stonefruit', 'peach': 'stonefruit', 'pear': 'stonefruit','orange': 'citrus', 'lemon': 'citrus', 'tangerine': 'citrus'}
similar_fruits = {}

for fruit in fruit_type:
  similar = []
  for comp in fruit_type:
    if fruit != comp:
      if fruit_type[fruit] == fruit_type[comp]:
        similar.append(comp)
  similar_fruits[fruit] = similar

print(similar_fruits)
```

`similar_fruits` will then be an automatic dictionary of all fruits and lists of each fruit they are similar to.
`{'apple': ['peach', 'pear'], 'peach': ['apple', 'pear'], 'pear': ['apple', 'peach'], 'orange': ['lemon', 'tangerine'], 'lemon': ['orange', 'tangerine'], 'tangerine': ['orange', 'lemon']}`

Hope this helps!
-Nate

Answer (score 0):

Then pair up each fruit with every similar fruit:

```
similar_pairs = [(f,sim) for f,sims in similar_fruit.items() for sim in sims]
```

Now ask if both members of the pair are in the same type:

```
for a,b in similar_pairs:
    if fruit_type[a] == fruit_type[b]:
        print(f"{a} and {b} are similar and the same kind")
```